# How to retrieve windows form check box status from a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application i have saved check box status  to a .txt file which is in string formate , and my problem is i want to retrieve check box status back to the respective check box ...

```
  private void Retrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using ( myStream)

                    {
                       // Insert code to read the stream here.
                       //textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        StraightLine.CheckState = lines[2];
                        StraightLine.CheckState = lines[4];
                        StraightLine.CheckState = lines[6];

                        }
                    }
                }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: i am getting an error i.e cannot convert string to windows form state.                      here is code where i am getting error StraightLine.CheckState = lines[2];
                        StraightLine.CheckState = lines[4];
                        StraightLine.CheckState = lines[6];

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is that `lines[2]` (and others) are of type `string`, but you need to assign a [CheckState enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value. What kind of text is in `lines[2]`? Is it an integer number, or is it the matching name of the enumeration (that is, "Checked", "Indeterminate", "Unchecked")?

Comment: string is in this formate "Checked" ,"Unchecked"

Comment: and i am saving check box status using this code objWriter.Write("straightline = " + "\n" + StraightLine.CheckState + "\n");
                       
                        objWriter.Write("Zigzagmotion = " + "\n" + ZigZagMotion.CheckState + "\n");
                        
                        objWriter.Write("Zmotion = " + "\n" + ZMotion.CheckState + "\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in `lines[2]`, `lines[4]`, and `lines[6]` are strings whereas the [`CheckBox.CheckState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires you to assign a [`CheckState` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value.

Assuming that the text value is the name representation, or underlying number representation of the enumeration values (that is, one of "Checked", "Indeterminate", "Unchecked", or "0", "1", "2"), then you can simply use the [`Enum.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert your text to a `CheckState` enumeration value:

```
StraightLine.CheckState = (CheckState)Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckState), lines[2]);
StraightLine.CheckState = (CheckState)Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckState), lines[4]);
StraightLine.CheckState = (CheckState)Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckState), lines[6]);
```